# How can I restart a list after range is exceeded in Python?

Tags: python-3.x

I am trying to to create a quick tool for seeing notes in a musical scale. The user enters a scale name and the program spits out the notes. For example, you enter C, then the output shows “C, D, E, F, G, A, B.” I have only the first two notes set up, without flats or sharps. To keep everything neat, I want to build the scale from a single array, only I don’t know how to loop back through the array. If the user enters G, it displays an error message that the range is exceeded. How can I make it so that after the user enters G, it prints G
“G, B?”

```
notes = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g']

scale_name = input('enter scale: ')

def scale_checker():
    if scale_name in notes:
        return(scale_name)
    elif scale_name not in notes:
        print('please enter valid scale')

start = notes.index(scale_name)

next_note = start +1 

print(notes[start],notes[next_note])
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python for loop with modulo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45839541/python-for-loop-with-modulo)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use slicing to print the values from `start` to the end of the list, and from the beginning of the list to `start`.

```
start = notes.index(scale_name)
print(*notes[start:] + notes[:start])
```